# MS Excel's Linest function in Java

Tags: java, excel

I am working on a Java application in which I need to use the "Linest" function in MS Excel. I have spent lot of time, but I could not find any suitable answers. Please do let me know if anybody knows something about it... many thanks in advance.

Comment: The information you want is [on this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics))

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but the formula does not give the same answer as that of excels Linest with first polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer. You can calculate the Linest exactly same as Excel, using a JAMA library. Refer the link below..
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/PolynomialRegression.java.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Apache Commons Math SimpleRegression](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html) which can be used to do simple linear regressions. Example :

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.SimpleRegression;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] data = { {1, 3}, {2, 7.9}, {3, 8}, {4, 9.2 }, {4.5, 12}, {5, 10.5}, {6, 15}};
        SimpleRegression regression = new SimpleRegression();
        regression.addData(data);
        System.out.println("y = "+ regression.getIntercept() + " + " + regression.getSlope() + " * x");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Eritrean, thanks for the reply, the SimpleRegression only gives the slope and intercept values. What I need is "Linest" output same as in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I know you were looking for an answer coded in Java, however here's an implementation of Excel's LINEST() function in C#, *without* having library dependencies. It returns the slope for a given set of data, normalized using the same "least squares" method that LINEST() uses:

```
public static double CalculateLinest(double[] y, double[] x)
{
   double linest = 0;
   if (y.Length == x.Length)
   {
      double avgY = y.Average();
      double avgX = x.Average();
      double[] dividend = new double[y.Length];
      double[] divisor = new double[y.Length];
      for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; i++)
      {
         dividend[i] = (x[i] - avgX) * (y[i] - avgY);
         divisor[i] = Math.Pow((x[i] - avgX), 2);
      }
      linest = dividend.Sum() / divisor.Sum();
   }
   return linest;
}
```

Also, here's a method I wrote to get the "b" (y-intercept) value that Excel's LINEST function generates.

```
private double CalculateYIntercept(double[] x, double[] y, double linest)
{
    return (y.Average() - linest * x.Average());
}
```

Since these methods only work for one set of data, I would recommend calling them inside of a loop if you wish to produce multiple sets of linear regression data.

This link helped me find my answer: https://agrawalreetesh.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-calculate-linest-of-given.html